# Is it possible to call secure flash SWF function from non secure page?

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, security, flash

I have a non secure (http) page, which is loading a secure (https) SWF and a secure (https) JS. When I try to call a Flash SWF function from the JS, it isn't getting called at all.

this.thisMovie(this.id).addButton(controlName);

I have crossdomain policy files properly defined in all the servers and Flash has the code added for Security.allowDomain("*"). *allowScriptAccess* is also set to *always*. The call works fine when the page is secure (https) or when everything is non secure.

I am wondering if it's even possible, and if yes, what do I need to do?

Comment: Please elaborate your question and show us what have you tried so far.

Comment: Well, I am not really sure what more I can elaborate. What information are you looking for? I have tried with crossdomain policies, allowScriptAccess flags, debugged to check if the method call is coming through for other all secure and all non secure scenarios. Everything works but this scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I just needed Security.allowInsecureDomain("*"); and everything worked. Thanks.